# Issue with the number of changes after I made on change after I cloned

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-actions

I have cloned a fresh version of the repository, created my own development branch, and made only one change in one file.

Now, that I want to see the changes, it shows 12K changes. Maybe it is comparing it to the main not the local. I am not sure.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @matt no, it's linux. That's strange. I use git status right after I compiled without any change, it shows a lot of changes.

Comment: Are there windows people contributing? — You see what I'm getting at? This could be a line endings issue.

Comment: Another possibility, I suppose, is that you somehow "cloned" not into a new folder but directly in your home folder, and placed your whole hard drive under Git control.

Comment: Please fix your tags. It can't be GitHub and GitLab simultaneously, and no GitHub Actions are involved.

Comment: If you run `git diff -- one/file/that/shouldnt/be/modified` in a terminal, what changes are shown ?